# Cannot route packets to VPN tunnel in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

It has been 3 days since I am stuck on this problem, I thought maybe someone here could point out something that I have missed.

We currently have an AWS VPC set up, with a VPN connection to one of our collaborator network. Therefore, we cannot manipulate the Customer Gateway since it doesn't belong to us. Anyway, **the VPN tunnel is up** and our collaborator allows traffic to one of their servers. The VPN uses **static routing**

Unfortunately, I cannot reach their server and a traceroute on an IP in their network doesn't tell me anything:

[image: Traceroute output (nothing interesting here, except if you're into stars)]

So here is a brief description of the topology:

```
VPC: X.X.X.0/24
EC2 instance: X.X.X.4 and X.X.X.211 (2 network interfaces)
Collaborator: Y.Y.Y.240/29
Collaborator's server: Y.Y.Y.241
My public IP: Z.Z.Z.Z/32
```

The route table of the VPC looks like this:

```
X.X.0.0/16 -> local
Z.Z.Z.Z/32 -> internet gateway
Y.Y.Y.240/29 -> virtual private gateway (Propagated)
```

ACLs and security groups does allow all kind of traffic (including ICMP) and I can connect to my server from my public IP. I just can't figure out why the packets emitted are not routed through the VPN tunnel. If anyone could point out something that I may have missed, that would be very appreciated.